# Telerik RadGrid EditTemplateColumn no value in textbox

Tags: validation, radgrid

I have a RadGrid and two columns. One Databound holding existing password and one EditTemplateColumn with a password confirmation textbox.

Since I want compare/validate the passwords I need to find the controls and the values.

The problem is that I can find the controls in the Radgrid ItemDataBound event, but not the inputed value for the confirm password textbox.

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Password" HeaderText="Password" UniqueName="Password" HeaderStyle-Width="130px" >
   <ColumnValidationSettings EnableRequiredFieldValidation="true" EnableModelErrorMessageValidation="true">
     <RequiredFieldValidator ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Password is missing"></RequiredFieldValidator>
     <ModelErrorMessage BackColor="Red" />
   </ColumnValidationSettings>
</telerik:GridBoundColumn>
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="PasswordConfirm" HeaderText="Confirm password" Display ="false" >
  <EditItemTemplate>
    <Telerik:RadTextBox ID="textBoxPasswordConfirm" Runat="server" >
    </Telerik:RadTextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="textBoxPasswordConfirm"
      ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Password missing" >
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
  </EditItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Here is the corresponding code:

```
GridEditableItem item = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
TextBox pwd1 = (TextBox)item["Password"].Controls[0];
RadTextBox pwdconfirm = (RadTextBox)item["PasswordConfirm"].FindControl("textBoxPasswordConfirm");
string t1 = pwd1.Text;
// the next line gives an empty string, and I do not understand why ????
string t2 = pwdconfirm.Text; 

TableCell cell = (TableCell)pwd1.Parent;
CompareValidator val = new CompareValidator();
val.ControlToValidate = pwd1.ID;
val.ControlToCompare = pwdconfirm.ID;
val.Operator = ValidationCompareOperator.NotEqual;
val.ErrorMessage = "Passwords do not match";
val.ForeColor = Color.Red;
cell.Controls.Add(val);
```

Comment: Thank's GhostCat ! I found it difficult to format the post in a nice way.

Comment: You are welcome. It takes a bit of practice, but as said: that preview window exists for a reason ;-) ... ideally, you just paste your input (without any indentation), then you mark it and click the { } icon, to indent as "source code". From there on, you just add more spaces where it makes sense.